# Error Repair SQL.sdf - The database encryption mode is invalid [ Input Encryption Mode = 0 ]

Tags: c#, sql, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I am in desperate need of help. I have a SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 database (`.sdf`).

My database is corrupted. I tried using `SqlCeEngine` but got an error when I run the `Repair` method:

> The database encryption mode is invalid [Input Encryption Mode = 0].

The problem is that my database is not encrypted and I do not have a password on the database.

I already put all kinds of encryption mode in the connection string but they all generate the same error.

Anyone have any idea what can I do?

Comment: And it is definitely a 3,5 database, and not 3,1 ?

Comment: Pls share your connection string

Answer (score 0):

Try the repair action from the CompactView tool:

http://sourceforge.net/p/compactview

Otherwise you can upgrade the DB to version 4.0